# PHP/MySQL; For loop to to insert rows only adds one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, mysqli

I'm using a `for` loop to add a specific number of rows to the table `Beds` as *placeholders*. The code doesn't throw any error, but only the last numbered bed appears in the database. I.e.: if you try to add 10 beds, only bed 10 gets added.

Here is the `for` loop I am using:

```
$roomName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['roomName']);
$numberBeds = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['numberBeds']);

for($x=1; $x <= $numberBeds; $x++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Beds (roomName, bedNumber, patientID) VALUES('$roomName','$x', NULL)";
}
```

And here is the accompanying table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ChildrensHospital`.`Beds` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ChildrensHospital`.`Beds` (
    `roomID` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `bedNumber` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `patientID` INT(20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`roomID`, `bedNumber`),
    INDEX `fk_Beds_PatientPersonalInformation1_idx` (`patientID` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Beds_PatientPersonalInformation1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patientID`)
    REFERENCES `ChildrensHospital`.`PatientPersonalInformation` (`patientID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm not sure if it's a syntax error in my PHP code, or something about the table itself. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you didn't run the query anywhere in the code posted. Likely, the query is called after the for loop has run, which is why only the last one is inserted...

Comment: Not likely - definitely. Look at the end of the line assigning to $sql

Comment: my guess is that, during the loop,  `$sql` just gets overwritten, then outside the loop is `mysql_query` which just executes a single statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not **executing** your query. Try it like this:

```
for($x=1; $x <= $numberBeds; $x++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Beds (roomName, bedNumber, patientID) VALUES('$roomName','$x', NULL)";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

I guess that you are only executing your query *after* the loop and thus, of course only the last query gets executed instead of each.